# Cypress click method don`t update page

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have written simple test with [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) but it don't update page on button `click()`. I have also tried to use `trigger('mouseenter').trigger('mousedown').trigger('mouseup')` - still no success, unsure why this happen. I have written same test with [fluentenium](http://fluentlenium.org/) - it works without problems.

Here is example of not working cypress script, [full code in github reproduce project](https://github.com/muzuro/cypress-click-issue/blob/master/cypress/integration/signup.js):

```
describe('Signup test', function() {
    it('Test signup flow', function() {
        cy.visit('https://qurasense.com')
        cy.contains('Sign up for participation').click()
        cy.get('.btn-yes > material-ripple').click()//don't work
        cy.get('[ngcontrol=firstName] input').should('be.visible')
    })
})
```

And here is working fluentenium alternative, [full code at github reproduce project](https://github.com/muzuro/cypress-click-issue/blob/master/fluentenium_tests/src/test/java/com/github/muzuro/SignUpIt.java):

```
@Test
public void testSignup() {
    goTo("https://qurasense.com");
    $("button", withText("Sign up for participation")).click();
    $(".btn-yes > material-ripple").click();
    assertThat($("[ngcontrol=firstName] input")).hasSize(1);
}
```

Could you give any tips why it can not work?

Comment: I just ran your test and it works fine, although when making a mod to the test chrome hung on reload (no indication why). Restarting chrome and the test, it again succeeds.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I think it could be realated to `dartdevc`. Test not work when I launch app in debug mode, but works when app is compiled to javascript.